# Replacing html content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Question:**

How would I go about replacing an html element and it's content with other content (**with javascript**)?

**Elaborating on what I mean:**

If I have the following html code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="element">some text</div>
    <div id="two" class="element">some text</div>
    <div id="three" class="element">some text</div>
    <div id="four" class="element">some text</div>
</div>
```

and I wanted to replace `<div id="two" class="element">some text</div>` with

```
<div id="a" class="element">some text</div>
<div id="b" class="element">some text</div>
```

to have the following result:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="element">some text</div>
    <div id="a" class="element">some text</div>
    <div id="b" class="element">some text</div>
    <div id="three" class="element">some text</div>
    <div id="four" class="element">some text</div>
</div>
```

how might I be able to do with with javascript?
**I know that I could do it in a hacky method:**

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 
    "<div id='one' class='element'>some text</div>" +
    "<div id='a' class='element'>some text</div>" +
    "<div id='b' class='element'>some text</div>" +
    "<div id='three' class='element'>some text</div>" +
    "<div id='four' class='element'>some text</div>";
```

But instead of having to replace everything just to replace 1 div with 2, I assume there is probably a cleaner way.. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Any documentation? Library?

Comment: @Amit at the bottom part of my question, I showed what I tried but the method was hacky and not ideal

Comment: Did you try reading jquery's documentation?

Comment: @Amit yes I did, but we don't always find what we are seeking. jszobody answered the question well though

Comment: It just doesn't seem you really tried to answer your own question - but perhaps I'm wrong. You should improve your searching skills though.. this is very basic and simple to find (there are other very common ways to do this as you see..) and knowing how to find what you need is crucial these days. Good luck!

Comment: @Amit no harm done bro :). In all honesty I did try to find it. Sometimes you get bad luck and it flies under your nose. I'm not very used to JQuery and only started Javascript recently, so I am still getting used to the layout of jQuery documentation page, though I obtain better results on php documentation cause I'm used to it. I'm sure I'll get used to the javascript / jquery documentation pages soon as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery, I'll assume an answer using jQuery is appropriate.

This is done quite easily with jQuery's [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
$("#container #two").replaceWith('<div id="a" ...');
```

See here: http://jsbin.com/dogikikefa/edit?html,js,output

---

Note you can use an array to pass in multiple pieces of html:

```
$("#container #two").replaceWith([
    '<div id="a" class="element">some replaced text</div>',
    '<div id="b" class="element">some replaced text</div>'
]);
```

I personally find that cleaner that the extra parenthesis or string concatenation.

http://jsbin.com/rodesabiru/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3):

You could use `replaceWith`

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $("#container #two").replaceWith( 
        ('<div id="a" class="element">some text</div>'),
           ('<div id="b" class="element">some text</div>') );
});
```

Comment: might I ask why you included an extra parenthesis? does it add a benefit? : `replaceWith( (...) )`

Comment: @Webeng: When you want to add multiple dom elements, it would be cleaner... Look at my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

#### Vanilla JS

```js
var div_two = document.getElementById('two');

// Create Div A
var div_a = document.createElement('div');
div_a.appendChild( document.createTextNode('some text a') );
div_a.setAttribute('id','a');
div_a.className = 'element';

// Create Div B
var div_b = document.createElement('div');
div_b.appendChild( document.createTextNode('some text b') );
div_b.setAttribute('id','b');
div_b.className = 'element';

// Where replacement occurs
var parent = div_two.parentNode;
parent.replaceChild(div_b, div_two);  // Replace Two with B
parent.insertBefore(div_a, div_b);    // Insert A before B
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="element">some text one</div>
    <div id="two" class="element">some text two</div>
    <div id="three" class="element">some text three</div>
    <div id="four" class="element">some text four</div>
</div>
```

*jQuery will certainly save you more lines of code, so if you're already using it you could do so here -- see other answers -- but understanding what jQuery is saving you from doing is important (ergo learn the Vanilla first)*

#### Automating

This demonstrates how to create any number of elements, by just populating the `['a','b','c','d']` array.  If you wanted different text or other elements, you could easily create an object (hash table) to pull from (`{ "a": { "textContent": "This is some value for this id" } }`).  Ideally this could be stored in a database; though if you're loading your front-end that way, you may want to look into other languages like Angular or React.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('two'),
    parent = target.parentNode;

// Create elements
var new_divs = [];
['a','b','c','d'].forEach(id=>{
   let new_div = document.createElement('div');
   new_div.setAttribute('id', id);
   new_div.className   = 'element';
   new_div.textContent = 'some text ' + id;
  
   new_divs.unshift( new_div );
});


// Add to page
new_divs.forEach((div,pass)=>{
   if (pass==0)
     parent.replaceChild( div, target );  // first pass replace
   else
     parent.insertBefore( div, target );  // all others insert before the last
  
   target = div;
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" class="element">some text one</div>
    <div id="two" class="element">some text two</div>
    <div id="three" class="element">some text three</div>
    <div id="four" class="element">some text four</div>
</div>
```

*jQuery will certainly save you more lines of code, so if you're already using it you could do so here -- see other answers -- but understanding what jQuery is saving you from doing is important (ergo learn the Vanilla first)*